# Thermal relief for a chip without metal plate on the bottom

Tags: integrated-circuit, temperature, thermal, kicad, footprint

I have a chip in which I have selected this footprint: `Package_SO: SOIC-8_3.9X4.9mm_P1.27mm`.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

Because this chip gets pretty hot, I thought I should keep the footprint but with vias for thermal relief. Something like this:

[image]

However, the chip is all plastic. There is no metal on the bottom to be soldered. Does it make sense to make a change like this? Will it help reduce the temperature?

Or because it cannot be soldered on the bottom, it will have no effect at all?

**EDIT:** This is a picture of the surrounding layout:
[image]

**EDIT2:** This is the layout for the whole portion that gets heated up:
[image]

**EDIT 3:** Following are images of the schematic topology, as well as a proposed layout for this boost converter.

[image]

[image]

EDIT 4: This is my attempt in copying user's user1850479 layout.
[image]

Comment: That looks like a switching converter.  Is it actually getting hot enough that this is a concern?  And if so, how much of that heat is from the adjacent diode and inductor?  Might make more sense to look at adding more thermal vias/planes to the area generally as heat will be coming from several closely packed components.

Comment: Show more of your layout. I have my doubts that this is actually the part getting hot; I suspect nearby parts are heating it instead, as user1850479 suggests.

Comment: It is true that the adjacent coil gets really hot as well. When I get back at home later, I will post pictures from the layout.

Comment: Actually, I just updated the question with a pic of the layout.

Comment: @Hearth Could it be that the layout is causing the problem?

Comment: That layout is not good for a switching converter. Can you post the whole thing, including the diode to capacitor hot loop? I suspect fixing the board will help a lot.

Comment: Actually it may be a better idea to post the full layout in a new question asking how to optimize that part. I've done boost converters on similar AZ chips, can probably help you optimize it.

Comment: @user1850479 I edited the question with the whole layout of the boost converter.

Comment: What is wrong about the layout? Is it the component placement geometry, or is it the distances between the components?

Comment: You're actually missing some of the boost converter in that picture, but I'll do my best.

Comment: A possiblity is to place the IC to the back of the board, if if's doable..

Comment: People using MC34063 in 2023?  There are grandparents younger than this thing. Significant size and cost savings can be had with a modern IC, by way of reduced capacitor and inductor sizes; and performance is vastly improved (higher efficiency, lower ripple).

Comment: This is the only chip that I found in LCSC for my specs. 12V in, up to 36V output. 1.5A max (in input). But as I am not experienced in this, maybe I messed things up.

Comment: The most likely candidates I would expect are: something SimpleSwitcher probably (don't have any numbers offhand), NCV3063 (an upgraded 34063, poorly stocked at the moment though), CS5171 (more expensive at LCSC than Digikey, lol), or a controller like LM3481 (both affordable and well stocked). If you're ordering assemblies through, uh, PCBWAY or whatever, you don't have to assemble everything from LCSC catalog parts, you can leave some off and put them on yourself, sourced from other distributors.

Answer (score 17):

The effect will be minimal without anything more thermal conductive than air between the chip and that thermal pad. What you can do is to increase the width of the traces, that will work way better.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned you’d have to have grease or another thermal interface material to make this work.  There should be some glues or epoxies that are compatible with a production process.  You could also glue a small Heatsink to the top.

Also maximize heat flow through the Vcc and GND pins.  Tie them well thermally to the planes/pours and you’ll be able to decrease temps a little.

But they do add those power pads for a reason.  You’ll want to change packages if you have significant dissipation.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain what you mean with this `Also maximize heat flow through the Vcc and GND pins. Tie them well thermally to the planes/pours and you’ll be able to decrease temps a little`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMWPe.png  Pin 1 and 8 are regular trace width, the others have more width, and GND pin (4) also Vcc (6) have largest width. GND is also connected through vias to a ground plane that will further spread the heat. So use wide traces from the pins a bit, those will work as a heatsink. Also heed user1850479s advice about hot components around the IC.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with a pic of the surrounding layout.

Answer (score 8):

If you cannot change to a different package, you'll get best heat conduction by having a large copper area for each pin:

[image: Example layout]

If the package had exposed metal pad, that would have a **direct connection** to the chip. Then it would make sense to just connect that to a big ground plane and have normal traces for other pins.

But the side pins connect to the chip through thin **bond wires**. Heat will have to transfer through the plastic enclosure to the pins, and then to the PCB. When each individual pin is a poor heat conductor, you want to use them all in parallel to make the best out of a poor situation.

Thermal conductive glue between the chip and PCB would be a good idea, but usually comes at an extra manufacturing cost. If you add the glue, adding ground plane vias under the chip is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! For the last paragraph, this stands correct even if the bottom of the chip is just plastic?

Comment: @user1584421 Yes, glue for plastic. If it was metal, you wouldn't need glue, it would get soldered in standard process.

Comment: Even with a metal bottom/case, we wouldn't solder that base to the thermal relief vias.  Makes rework more complicated.  A thermal pad is our preferred approach.

Comment: @SteveSh Yeah, every time you improve heat conduction, rework gets harder. Depends on exact situation what is more important.

Comment: It depends on the chip; there are some leaded devices that have one or more leads connected to the die bond pad, they don't all use wirebonds for all leads. This is common for SOIC-8 and SOT-23-6 (maybe also SOT-23-3) MOSFETs, as I understand it.

Comment: @Hearth True, discrete semiconductors (as opposed to integrated circuits) have different packaging methods. I guess there is technically nothing stopping a custom leadframe with some of the normal pins going underneath the chip, but I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is actually the enormous high current switching loop you have routed through your board.  It is so large it does not fit in your picture, but here is the part of it I can see:

[image]

Depending on how far it goes to the right of the board before meeting back up and closing the loop it is actually a little surprising the converter works at all.

Here is a better layout for that converter:

[image]

By putting the diode and MLCC capacitor right up against the switch, current only flows a few millimeters and all on one layer, so it encounters only a small amount of resistance and inductance which leads to lower losses and better performance.  Furthermore that distance is mostly connected with wide planes that have lower resistance/inductance.  Note that depending on the switching frequency you may also want to put that big electrolytic capacitor in too, but you can parallel the MLCC to keep the loop area small and put the electrolytic slightly further out.

When I built that converter like this the chip did not get particularly hot.

**Edit**:  If you wanted to try and salvage the existing board, you could try adding an MLCC and a (short!) jumper wire here:

[image]

That would reduce the loop to the green area.  You could test that and see if the temperature is reduced.

Comment: The 2nd layout is indeed how it should be done. The 1st one had no chance at working well.

Comment: First of all, I cannot thank you enough for taking the time to not only answer my question, but experimenting with this by yourself. My gratitude is immense! Secondly, this is the third board that I design, so terms like "high current switching loop" are not only unknown for me, but I don't even know where you learn these things.... It makes sense that I messed this up, as my skill is not even close to being a good PCB designer. One last thing. I am not sure if this is the correct site to suggest this, but I am willing to pay you to make a shared screen review of my board/help me with the

Comment: layout. If you are not interested, please excuse my offer. Otherwise, I can make a deposit (paypal?) and we can sit for 30-60 mins to examine the board, if you are up to it. Whatever you decide, I am extremely grateful for your help! Take care!

Comment: @user1584421 I did the design previously, so no trouble to share.  Here is a white paper that I found useful:  https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/layout-for-power-designs-1-hot-loops.html  I'm not able to take more paid work at the moment, but it is common for people to post designs here and ask for feedback.

Comment: It's ok I understand! I tried to replicate what you did, to the extent that I could because the ICs are not the same. I updated my question. One picture is the schematic topology of the boost converter. The last picture is an experiment, in trying to replicate your design. Could you please take a look at it? If you look at the ratsnest, does everything look ok to you? If not, could you please recommend some changes in the layout? Thank a ton!

Comment: I disagree, backhandedly: not to say the layout wan't bad (it was), or the suggested layout is (it's excellent!), but to imply that the IC in question is so archaic that it won't even mind such a poor layout.

Comment: @user1584421 I believe we both used the same IC, so you could use my layout exactly, or at least very similar. If you want to do your own layout, draw the circle I did between the switch pins, the output capacitor and the diode and see if they form a tight circle. If they don't, try to improve it until they do. It's only three components, so not too hard to put them into a triangle.

Comment: I counted surounding components (you can see them in the attached picture) and they are 9, but yours are 10. This is why I assumed it's another IC... The two vertical components in the leftmost of the picture what are they? Resistors or Caps? Also the two parallel components at the green circle... One of them is C4, but what type of compoenent is the other? Thank you very much and sorry for all the trouble....

Comment: @user1584421 I paralleled two input capacitors and two output capacitors to hit the capacitance I wanted, so all four of those are capacitors.  You can ignore that and use your electrolytics instead.

Comment: Thank you immensely. I copied your layout and i updated the question with a picture of my attempt. There is one thing which I am uncertain. In your layout, `D1` is "fed" from `pad 2` of the coil, which is "fed" from `U1 - pad 1`. In my version, `D1` is fed from `U1 - pad 1` directly, and then it goes to the coil. Does this create unwanted current loops, or is it not of concern? BTW, can i omit the electrolytic capacitors? In your version, you used two MLCCs, in order to substitute one electrolytic. Is this a valid thing to do? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1584421 I ended up putting an electrolytic in mine as well, it is just shared with another circuit so further away from the regulator.  I tested increasing the switching frequency to use lower capacitance but ended up not being satisfied without the electrolytic. In your case, I would consider putting an MLCC in tight and then moving the electrolytic further out.  The inductor current is relatively constant (inductors hold current constant), so routing is not so critical as the switching loop.  Planes are a good idea though if you expect high current.

Comment: The max expected current is 1.5Amps (in the input of the boost IC). I have the whole upper copper plane as GND, and the bottom as 5V. My design is based completely upon the datasheet of the IC. Thus if I place another MLCC capacitor, this would be beyond the datasheet. Would this help with the current loop? If yes, what capacitance should I use?

Comment: I received my pcbs with your layout. I tested the pcb and within 5 minutes of connecting the load, the diode (or at least the diode only) was burnt. I don't know what is responsible for it. I opened up a question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/684485/step-up-circuit-burns-protection-diode

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to make a change like this? Will it help reduce the
> temperature?
>
> Or because it cannot be soldered on the bottom, it will have no effect at all?

It won't if the package doesn't have a pad directly on the bottom, there will still be air and plastic between the die and the PCB and neither of those will be great a transferring heat.

If you want to get rid of the air, use thermal heatsink compound or a thermal glue on the bottom of the chip. But the PCB isn't the best place to dump heat, because it simply heats up the PCB. The best place is to dump it in a heatsink and the heat ends up in the air (If you dump heat in a pcb it just heats up the PCB and then the PCB heats up the air, but you end up with a hot PCB). Even a small piece of metal can make a significant difference in transfering heat to the air. Even better would be a small heatsink.

The best thing to do for a DC DC switcher would be to reduce the current or make sure the design is correct.

Comment: Many applications don't have the availability of free air for cooling, and have to conduct heat through the PCB to a suitable heat sink.  Military and satellite applications fall in this category.