# Step up circuit burns protection diode

Tags: power, diodes, boost, temperature, step-up

I have implemented a step up circuit using an IC. I implemented the component selection from the datasheet. This is its datasheet.

[image: step-up converter schematic from datasheet]

Image source: [LCSC - AZ34063U datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809251831_Diodes-Incorporated-AZ34063UMTR-G1_C99659.pdf)

The step up feeds an H-bridge.  The H-bridge offers two pins with an alternating power output that feeds a load.

I received my boards, and I connected the load and put the PCB to the test, to see how hot the chip would get.

After some minutes, I accidentally disconnected one pin of the load that was connected to the H-bridge.

Then I saw smoke coming out, and two seconds later I saw sparks coming out of the diode. The diode was destroyed.

I am not sure if the destruction of the diode is due to the removal of one pin of the load from the H-bridge output, or if that happened at that exact time coincidentally and perhaps other reasons, such as the temperature were the culprit.

[This is the diode I used.](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_JSMSEMI-1N5819WS-S4_C2927280.html)

The output voltage was 30V, and the load was consuming a 0.25A current.

EDIT: Suggestion made by user Russell McMahon

[image]

Comment: You need to show the H-bridge and please explain which diode you are referring to. Add links to relevant data sheets please.

Comment: You mean schematic or layout?

Comment: The diode D1 is NOT a protection diode - it is the output rectifier for theboost converter. Under load the circuit will regulate using R1 and R2. Under no load the energy in the inductor in one switching cycle MAY be enough to drive the output voltagfehigher or far higher than designed. The1N5819 is rated at 40 volts. A disconnected load is a reasonable reason for its demise.  Placing a zener diode at the output with perhaps a small series resistor will stop no load deaths. 29v < Vz < 40V || (MC34063 - very olde indeed. Still useful :-). I've used several 100,000 of them).

Comment: Thanks! Although in the version 2 of the pcb, I am (almost) certain that if I had disconnected one pole of the load, the diode would not burn. I will experiment today with the old layout, to see If it will burn.

Comment: I just tried my v2. I disconnected one pole of the load, and I never had an issue with a burnt diode. You can see my v2 layout in thie question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/681868/thermal-relief-for-a-chip-without-metal-plate-on-the-bottom

Comment: So perhaps this is not the reason of its demise? However, I am willing to try out your circuit, to see the results. `Placing a zener diode at the output with perhaps a small series resistor will stop no load deaths.` Where exactly do I place this? The output of the step Up or the HBridge?

Comment: @user1584421 - Hi, I see you have written comments, but didn't use `@username` notifications - explained [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019). FYI without those: (a) people may not guess who each comment is intended for (so you may not get replies, or may not get them from the expected person); (b) unless comment-writers clicked the "Follow" link, they won't get any notification about *your* comments and therefore may not see them & may not reply. || I always recommend using `@username` in comments :)

Comment: Have you simulated your circuit? Please post your schematic.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon While personally I am not sure if this is the problem, because after countless attempts, I was not able to replicate it, I also am inexperienced. I take your word for it, based on your immense experience with this chip. Is it too much to ask, where exactly do I place the Zener diode and the resistor? And also, what value should that resistor be? (Why are these two components not referenced in the datasheet schematic?)

Comment: @winny I haven't simulated it. The schematic is pretty much what you see in the picture. Whats extra is that the output goes to an HBridge, as well as two control signals to the HBridge as well.

Comment: Please simulate everything before building. Please post your exact schematic with your exact component values.

Comment: @user1584421 A zener plus maybe resistor in series is placedfrom Vout to ground. || My "solution" is not magic but rather that something which provides a sacrificial target in place of the diode **IF** Vout rises higher than intended, regardless of why. This will work for any power supply - for a long as the zener survives :-). || What it does is absorb any energy above Vz. If Vz is say 33V and robust enough to absorb a single cycle of inductor energy then it will face any energy surge first. IF the IC is regulating correctly there will only be one initial suge, if any.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I edited my question with a schematic. Is this what you are suggesting? And one last thing.. Do you know why it's impossible to replicate this problem? Is it extremely timing dependent on when the inductor will unload the energy?

Comment: @user1584421 Yes - zener position is correct - BUT you show its polarity reversed - it should block voltages under about 30V. || It's not possible to be CERTAIN that this is the problem as eg the diode may be being marginally stressed by the startup cycle. ||  I'd expect this NOT to happen as inductor should store about 150 uJ at about 1.5A current limit - If @ 330 uF  C2 should store about 500 uJ at 30V so should not be "overvolted in one cycle. Even 2 cycles (first just below Vreg) should only get it to 300 uJ. || **IS C2 =  330 uF?** If say 100 uF it would be more likely to happen

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes, the capacitor C2 is 330uF. Well the diode is rated at 40V, but the max voltage of the Step Up IC is 36V. Therefore, I guess I should choose a Vz=37V? Is that correct? Also, `power dissipation`, `zener impedance` and `reverse leakage current`.. Are these important parts in selecting a Zener?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I also have to note, that the circuit gets power from a power supply 12V. 1.5Amps. this is 18W. What Wattage should the Zener diode have? I found one that is 500mW...

Comment: @user1584421  Zener voltage should be "not much above maximum Vout" - ie about 33V in this case. Zeners have a "soft knee" and you can expect a few volts above rated value for a large spike. || Shorting the output to ground may destroy D1. || A 500 mW zener should be OK. If it dies then the system is probably not regulating as it should. Note as mentioned previously that polarity should be opposite of what you have shown. || Zener dissipation matters. Impedance and leakage are not too important here.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I should note that this circuit outputs 36V max output. Therefore I guess a Zener of 39V would be ok.|| `Shorting the output to ground may destroy D1. ` What do you mean with this exactly? || Can you offer some info on what `Power Dissipation` I should target?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I know that Max Voltage = 36V. Max Amps in the exit is about 0.3A. This means that the input of the Step-Up will have about 1.5A max. What Amps should I consider (input or output), in order to calculate the Watts, to determine the Power Dissipation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. BUT | Max amps on output short is V/R = Vin /(0.22 + R_inductor) .   An output short can destroy D1 unless R_inductor is over several Ohms || If regulating the energy in 1 cycle from the inductor cannot destroy D1. || If NOT regulating for whatever reason then Vout can rise to Vzener + a bit or to very high without the zener. WITH the zener the diode should never die (except when Vout is short circuited) unless the zener dies first. IF the zener dies then the circuit is not regulating. All this assumes that the actual circuit matches theory. || Try the zener.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 1. Max vout = 36. So Vz should be > 36 and < 40? 2. In order to calculate the Wattage for the Power Dissipation, I take into consideration the IC's output current or input current? Because while the output current is 0.3A, the IC's input current is 1.5A max.... 3. For this equation `V/R = Vin /(0.22 + R_inductor)`... Is this the Max I that the IC can provide? This is Ohm's Law, but when does this equation is calculated (at what conditions)? With that value, how can I calculate the `Power Dissipation` that I need for the Zener?

Comment: IF YOUR INTENDED Vout_max is 36V then a zener > 36V is needed. || If your Vout max INTENDED is 36V then  a 40V diode is too marginal. || Zener is to absorb possible excess voltage from converter. Short circuit and other currents do not affect the zener. || I have commented on Zener power rating above. || The short circuit current is the path from Vin via 0.22Ohm resistor, via inductor, via D1 and then to ground via the short. It is unrelated to the IC ratings. At startup C2 at the output (and C3 if load connected) act as shorts util they charge.

Comment: || You need to try to follow explanations. When I mention shorts at output and give a formula try to see how I arrived at the expression. More questions are fine, but try hard to see what explanations and formulas mean. || We ALL had to start somewhere, so hang in there ! :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon First of all I want to thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions. I really appreciate it. Sorry for the bulk of questions, its the first time working with Zeners. My last question if for the Power Dissipation. I re-read all your comments, but I still do not know which Power Dissipation to choose.... Could you help me with that please?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon My question regarding power dissipation is this: `The maximum power dissipation that can be allowed in a Zener, is the Zener voltage multiplied by the current flowing through it`.  The Zener voltage selected is 39V. However, I am uncertain about the current. Do I select the output current of the IC, drawn by the load (in which case it is 0.3A), or do I select the input current of the IC, in which case it is 1.5A?

Comment: @user1584421 39V is too high of you are trying to protect a 40V diode. 40 V is the ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM fir a [1N5819](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/26/db/14/60/52/47/47/5b/CD00001625.pdf/files/CD00001625.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001625.pdf) || WHAT IS YOUR MAXIMUM OUTPUT VOLTAGE? So far I have seen figures of 29V, 33V and now 39V. || 500 mW zener I/V curves are seen [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85604/bzx55.pdf) in fig 9. Even 36V zener is marginal for a 40V diode protection. || As above - the zener is to protect against MAYBe one time ...

Comment: ... startup energy OR maybe non regulatiom. In the latter case Pzener needs to be greater than what the converter than prodice **BUT** if that is happening you have other problems. || A 500 mW zener should work. BUT your Vout, regardless should not be over say 36V with that diode. || Again - what is your MAXIMUMdesired output voltage? || Have you added the recommended one Ohm input resistor and input capacitor?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon My Max Vout is 36V. As for `Have you added the recommended one Ohm input resistor and input capacitor?` I am not sure what you mean. I have implemented everything in that picture in the datasheet.

Comment: @user1584421 Read my answer. || There I say "... Adding Antonio51's extra input R7 of 1 Ohm and C3 of 100 uF will lower Ipeak and reduce this possible cause. ...". This isshowin Antonio51's answer in his 4t diagram. || What did you think thjat I was referring to in my answer? || Note that the zener and this resistor cover two unrelated / independent **possible** failure modes. Of the two the resistor related one seems the most likely.

Comment: @user1584421  As above, 36V is VERY close to the limit for a 40V diode. Ideally you'd use a higher voltage diode.

Answer (score 3):

Made with [microcap](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110) v12 FREE

Here is the behavior of this IC.
Note that there is no capacitor at the input which should "break" the input pulse current.

Just note the high current at the start ... current or no current into the load.

[image]

Load wired ...

[image]

Just change the "slew-rate" of input power ...

[image]

And here are the "powers" ...

[image]

Comment: Hi Antonio! Thank you for the answer! I just placed some comments on the other answer. Perhaps you find them useful! Thank you for the graphs, but I am having trouble understanding them. Do they reveal the issue for the demise of the diode?

Comment: Just "perhaps" change the slew rate of input power (your capacitor C1 at input ...)

Comment: This is the capacitor that I used: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Aluminum-Electrolytic-Capacitors-span-style-background-color-ff0-SMD-span_ROQANG-RVE1C101M0605_C99838.html

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding... What do I have to change to the capacitor? What does slew rate translates to? Is this a valid reason why the diode got burnt? If yes, what does the diode does not burn in the same circuit (different layout - older version)

Comment: No. Don't change the capacitor. It is "ok". I simulated the "opening"  of the load. Nothing to say (see new simulation). Don't understand why the diode got burned.

Comment: Thank you very much for the trouble of simulating.

Comment: No worries for that.

Comment: @user1584421 & Antonio: The startup current surge is the equivalent of briefly shorting the output. This is due to charging C2 30 uF. Fig 15 on page 5 of [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/26/db/14/60/52/47/47/5b/CD00001625.pdf/files/CD00001625.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001625.pdf) shows the peak allowed non repetitive single cycle current is 25A - which is about 2 x what Antonio51's simulations show. HOWEVER fig 10 page 3 suggests a 1mS peak of under 8A.  The simulation shows somewhat less time BUT 50% more current.  ...

Comment: ... This seems very marginal. Addig A's extra input 1 Ohm and C3 100 uF will drop Ipeak to under 3 amps and eliminate this possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

This complements Antonio51's answer.

Summary:

- A look at the diode's single non repetitive surge current ratings and Antonio51's simulations suggests that diode D1 is being run at at least 150% of its single surge rating and maybe more depending on the startup surge duration. Adding the 1 Ohm series resistor plus capacitor that Antonio51 shows in his final diagram should eliminate this possible failure mode.

---

The startup current surge is the equivalent of briefly shorting the output. This is due to charging C2, 30 uF.
Fig 15 on page 5 of [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/26/db/14/60/52/47/47/5b/CD00001625.pdf/files/CD00001625.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001625.pdf) shows the peak allowed non repetitive single cycle current is 25A - which is about 2 x what Antonio51's simulations show.

HOWEVER fig 10 page 3 suggests an allowed 1mS peak of under 8A.  The simulation shows somewhat less time BUT 50% more current.
This seems very marginal.

Adding Antonio51's extra input R7 of 1 Ohm and C3 of 100 uF will lower Ipeak and reduce this possible cause. (At 8A surge this will drop 8V, so 8A will not happen. As an 8A <= 1 ms surge is (just) acceptable and the actual will be lower again "all should be well".

---

Note:  The output zener that I mention elswhere has no useful role in this fault mode.